Tensorflow val accuracy is stuck for classifying images
I'm doing a challenge to create a classification for some images. I have 10.000 train images and 3.000 validation images, with 3 classes. But I can't increase my validation accuracy whatever I try. I am looking for any ideas/explanations or solutions
I started with a simple, base model:
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
    ])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

for 15 epochs:
epochs = 15
history = model.fit(
  train_dataset,
  validation_data=val_dataset,
  epochs=epochs
)

this results in around 90 accuracy for train data, but the val_acc never grows. It stagnates around 0.34
165/165 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 30s 98ms/step - accuracy: 0.3933 - loss: 1.4266 - val_accuracy: 0.3377 - val_loss: 1.1598
Epoch 2/15
165/165 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9s 55ms/step - accuracy: 0.5214 - loss: 0.9857 - val_accuracy: 0.3497 - val_loss: 1.2092
Epoch 3/15
165/165 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9s 55ms/step - accuracy: 0.5849 - loss: 0.9057 - val_accuracy: 0.3513 - val_loss: 1.3415
Epoch 4/15
165/165 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9s 55ms/step - accuracy: 0.6281 - loss: 0.8238 - val_accuracy: 0.3470 - val_loss: 1.5618
Epoch 5/15
165/165 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9s 56ms/step - accuracy: 0.6877 - loss: 0.7123 - val_accuracy: 0.3460 - val_loss: 1.8965
Epoch 6/15
165/165 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9s 55ms/step - accuracy: 0.7389 - loss: 0.6132 - val_accuracy: 0.3390 - val_loss: 2.1827
Epoch 7/15
165/165 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9s 55ms/step - accuracy: 0.7600 - loss: 0.5644 - val_accuracy: 0.3467 - val_loss: 2.2611
Epoch 8/15
165/165 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9s 55ms/step - accuracy: 0.8277 - loss: 0.4246 - val_accuracy: 0.3347 - val_loss: 2.5835
Epoch 9/15
165/165 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9s 55ms/step - accuracy: 0.8561 - loss: 0.3664 - val_accuracy: 0.3447 - val_loss: 2.6086
Epoch 10/15
165/165 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9s 56ms/step - accuracy: 0.8892 - loss: 0.2964 - val_accuracy: 0.3380 - val_loss: 3.0506
Epoch 11/15
165/165 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9s 55ms/step - accuracy: 0.9051 - loss: 0.2513 - val_accuracy: 0.3350 - val_loss: 3.1805
Epoch 12/15
165/165 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9s 55ms/step - accuracy: 0.9211 - loss: 0.2048 - val_accuracy: 0.3413 - val_loss: 3.9698
Epoch 13/15
165/165 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9s 55ms/step - accuracy: 0.9407 - loss: 0.1620 - val_accuracy: 0.3350 - val_loss: 4.6286
Epoch 14/15
165/165 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9s 55ms/step - accuracy: 0.9620 - loss: 0.1211 - val_accuracy: 0.3407 - val_loss: 5.1370
Epoch 15/15
165/165 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9s 56ms/step - accuracy: 0.9679 - loss: 0.0912 - val_accuracy: 0.3460 - val_loss: 5.4826

I clearly seen this as a overfitting sign at first, but after numerous tries like:

reducing/increasing the layers size
Adding dropout
Different sizes and augumentation for the photos

with no success, I can't stop but wonder what am I doing wrong
this is my final twist for the model in order to prevent the overfitting / increase my val accuracy:
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential(
  [
    
    tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(0.1),
  ]
)

def create_model():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(80, 80, 3)),
    data_augmentation,
    tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    #tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    #tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    #tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    #tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    #tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
    ])
  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
       
              metrics=['accuracy'])

  return model

model = create_model()

what is commented means it has been tried
and nothing changed, my val_accuracy stood at 0.33-0.35 the whole time, even though now my train accuracy hits around 0.7.
This made me think, maybe I am doing something wrong with preparing the data?
for context, this is how I get my data for this:
import os
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
import numpy as np

# Set the paths to the competition's input directory
input_dir = '/image-classification'  

# Paths to CSV files and image directories
train_csv_file = os.path.join(input_dir, 'train.csv')  
val_csv_file = os.path.join(input_dir, 'validation.csv')  

train_image_dir = os.path.join(input_dir, 'train')  
val_image_dir = os.path.join(input_dir, 'validation') 
# Load the CSV files
train_df = pd.read_csv(train_csv_file)
val_df = pd.read_csv(val_csv_file)


# Function to load and preprocess images
def load_and_preprocess_image(image_id, img_dir, target_size=(224, 224)):
    img_path = os.path.join(img_dir, f"{image_id}.png")  
    img = load_img(img_path, target_size=target_size)  # Load the image with target size
    img_array = img_to_array(img)  # Convert the image to an array
   
    return img_array

# Function to load images and labels from a dataframe
def load_images_and_labels(df, img_dir):
    images = []
    labels = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        image_id = row['image_id']
        label = row['label']
        try:
            image = load_and_preprocess_image(image_id, img_dir)
            images.append(image)
            labels.append(label)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"Image {image_id} not found, skipping.")
    return np.array(images), np.array(labels)


X_train, y_train = load_images_and_labels(train_df, train_image_dir)

# Load validation images and labels
X_val, y_val = load_images_and_labels(val_df, val_image_dir)

# Create TensorFlow datasets
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_val, y_val))


# Batch and prefetch the datasets
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(64).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(64).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

Any ideas?

Have u tried with pre-trained model, i.e. efficientnet?

@Innat that is not an option, I would like to create this model myself in order to come to a better understanding of what's happening in situations like this

It seems you are defining the optimizer but not using it in the model.compile. Replace 'adam' with optimizer .
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001) 

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer ,
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
               
    metrics=['accuracy'])

Also, try to make the model simpler, try to increse drop out to 0.5, and use a different optimizer such as SGD.
